# Why is there a difference between std::function constructor or assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, perfect-forwarding

The `std::function` type erasure constructor is defined as:

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

The assignment operator is defined as:

```
template< class F >
function& operator=( F&& f );
```

(source cppreference)

Why does the constructor gets `f` by value while `operator=` gets `f` by forwarding reference?

Comment: But `std::function` has multiple constructors and multiple operator=. Including a move constructor that corresponds to the move operator=.

Comment: @michalsrb in his example `F&&` is not a r-value-reference

Comment: The same question seems to have been asked here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/ozZQh6dEsiA

Answer (score 3):

I can only guess, but I would guess it is because it was added to C++ while rvalue references and forwarding references where being added to the language.

So some parts of its API got forwarding references, and some did not.

There is one minor advantage: if the copy constructor of `F` could throw while the move cannot, `std::function( F )` can be guaranteed not to throw, while `std::function( F const& )` cannot be.  The difference is that the copy would be done outside the constructor in the `template<class F> function(F)` case, but inside the constructor in the `template<class F> function(F&&)` case when passed a non-rvalue.

This is not a compelling reason.

It would also make it marginally easier to specify the SFINAE behavior of `function(F)`, but that wasn't formalized until long after C++11, so that cannot be the reason.

The cost to `template<class F>function(F)` is low -- one move of `F` over the perfect forwarding version -- so it probably hasn't been high on anyone's priority list to change (especially because it causes a subtle change in the "could throw" tests of `function(F)`, and hence could actually in theory cause some strange code to break).

Comment: but if that so, why does `std::function::assign` is deprecated in C++17 but the signature of the constructor is not changed? that means someone did put some thought on improving `std::function` API, yet, they left the copy-the-callable-constructor unchanged